# Np.Linspace gives me empty array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have to reassign some variables in my file, however, when I create the array, it spits out an empty array. 
So what I have is :

lat = np.linspace(90.0,-90.0,-1/6)

Here I am just trying to get a list that is 1080 long and between 90 and -90. It has to be in that order to match the data associated with it. When I print (lat) I get '[]'. 
There is also this associated with the print statement

'/gpfs/u/apps/dav/opt/python/3.6.4/intel/17.0.1/pkg-library/20180512/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: DeprecationWarning: object of type  cannot be safely interpreted as an integer'
Not sure what that means...

I have also tried arange with 1080 at the end, however I get the same thing.

Comment: Take another look at the [`linspace` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).  Note, in particular, the meaning of the third argument.

Comment: Looks like you're confusing `arange` and `linspace` - `arange` takes a `step` (your `-1/6` - which, by the way is `-1` - if you want float use `-1./6` or something similar) and `linspace` takes a number of elements.